# Dbeaver does not display "Table description" of table in a Hive database

Tags: hadoop, hive, dbeaver

I created a Hive table with table description metadata using this command:

```
create table sbx_ppppp.comments (
     s string comment 'uma string',
     i int comment 'um inteiro'
) comment 'uma tabela com comentários';
```

But it isn't correctly displayed when I double click the table:

[image: Table properties without description]

The table description also isn't displayed in the table tooltip or in the table list when I double click the database name.

When I run the `describe formatted table sbx_ppppp.comments` command with the comment is correctly displayed as table property:

```
col_name                    |data_type                                       |comment                                                                    |
----------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# col_name                  |data_type                                       |comment                                                                    |
s                           |string                                          |uma string                                                                 |
i                           |int                                             |um inteiro                                                                 |
                            |                                                |                                                                           |
# Detailed Table Information|                                                |                                                                           |
Database:                   |sbx_ppppp                                       |                                                                           |
OwnerType:                  |USER                                            |                                                                           |
Owner:                      |ppppp                                           |                                                                           |
CreateTime:                 |Fri Apr 29 18:31:31 BRT 2022                    |                                                                           |
LastAccessTime:             |UNKNOWN                                         |                                                                           |
Retention:                  |0                                               |                                                                           |
Location:                   |hdfs://BNDOOP03/corporativo/sbx_ppppp/comments  |                                                                           |
Table Type:                 |MANAGED_TABLE                                   |                                                                           |
Table Parameters:           |                                                |                                                                           |
                            |COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE                           |{\"BASIC_STATS\":\"true\",\"COLUMN_STATS\":{\"i\":\"true\",\"s\":\"true\"}}|
                            |bucketing_version                               |2                                                                          |
                            |comment                                         |uma tabela com comentários                                                 |
                            |numFiles                                        |0                                                                          |
                            |numRows                                         |0                                                                          |
                            |rawDataSize                                     |0                                                                          |
                            |totalSize                                       |0                                                                          |
                            |transactional                                   |true                                                                       |
                            |transactional_properties                        |default                                                                    |
                            |transient_lastDdlTime                           |1651267891                                                                 |
                            |                                                |                                                                           |
# Storage Information       |                                                |                                                                           |
SerDe Library:              |org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde       |                                                                           |
InputFormat:                |org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat |                                                                           |
OutputFormat:               |org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat|                                                                           |
Compressed:                 |No                                              |                                                                           |
Num Buckets:                |-1                                              |                                                                           |
Bucket Columns:             |[]                                              |                                                                           |
Sort Columns:               |[]                                              |                                                                           |
Storage Desc Params:        |                                                |                                                                           |
                            |serialization.format                            |1                                                                          |
```

In "Table Parameters" you can see the value "uma tabela com comentários" for the "comment" parameter.

I'm using Cloudera ODBC driver version 2.6.11.1011 to connect to Hive. DBeaver is version 22.0.3.202204170718. I don't know if this is a [bug in DBeaver](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/16374) or in Cloudera ODBC driver. Maybe I'm not correctly setting the table description.